# EXCEL : Applying SortBy for Unique-Filter function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got following issue in the Excel

I tried following functions but struggling to get the result I needed in column E

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(SORTBY(A2:A15, C2:C15,1),B2:B15="EU", ""))`

`=LET(x, FILTER(A2:C5,B2:B15="EU",""), SORTBY(x,INDEX(x,0,3),1))`

[image]

Comment: I am not sure how is that formula working for you, can you try this and let me know `=LET(x,SORTBY(A2:C15,C2:C15,1),
UNIQUE(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(x,1),CHOOSECOLS(x,2)="EU")))`

Comment: Ok, so this is the correction for your formula with `LET()` ==> `=LET(x, FILTER(A2:C15,B2:B15="EU",""), UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(SORTBY(x,INDEX(x,0,3),1),1)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using: `DROP()` Function

[image]

• Formula used in cell `G2`

```
=LET(x,FILTER(A2:C15,B2:B15="EU"),UNIQUE(DROP(SORTBY(x,DROP(x,,2),1),,-2)))
```